# Sending E-Mail from a form fails only in deployed state of my Webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httprequest, visual-studio-2019

so I made a contact form for sending an E-Mail with Data from my Webpage, which works perfectly fine when I debug it in Visual Studio 2019, but doesn't work when I put it in the Webhost (Ionos) and let it run on the WWW. I tried logging the error with ElmahCore but can't really figure out how to fix this error. It gives me this error:
**System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.**
The Code I wrote in C# is the following:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
        {
           
            if (!ReCaptchaPassed(Request.Form["foo"]))
            { 
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "You failed the CAPTCHA.");
                return Page();
            }

           
            
                MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
                string nachricht = "";

                nachricht += "Some Message";
                mm.Body = nachricht;
                mm.From = new MailAddress("MyPersonalEmail);
                mm.To.Add(new MailAddress("MyPersonalEmail"));
                mm.Subject = "Buchung";
                mm.IsBodyHtml = false;

                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("MyPersonalEmail", "MyPersonalPassword");
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(mm);
            

            ViewData["Message"] = "Some Message";
            return Page();
        }
```

Every help really is appreciated and I hope I described the problem accurately enough. If any questions or if I oversaw some details I shouldve added feel free to ask :)

Comment: There are a couple reasons this error can occur 1) The server is on a corporate network where the smtp port number is blocked because there is a outlook proxy server and firewall that does not allow a connection to a foreign mail server like gmail 2) The credentials are wrong (smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("MyPersonalEmail", "MyPersonalPassword");)  The gmail account doesn't recognize the credentials.  You would need to go into Control Panel User Mail and setup a pop account on the webserver.

Comment: Have you enabled 'Less Secure Apps' in your Google account settings? - In order to send via SMTP you need to enable this setting - The official way to send emails via Gmail is to use [Google's API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending)

Comment: Yes I did enable "Less Secure Apps" in my Google Account. I already had to do this when I debugged my Webpage in VS, so that is not the error :/

Comment: @jdweng Your first point seems interesting, this might be the error. 2) and 3) shouldn't be the error as it works in Debug Mode (I changed the Credential here ofc). Do u maybe have a solution if 1) is the error?

Comment: The proxy server is used to prevent hackers from creating a virus that looks like another outlook email server.  I've tried a long time ago to find a work around for the proxy server and was not successful.  You would need you MIS support for adding a proxy serve that would forward email to gmail instead of the corporate outlook server.